# how do I stop a scene and play the next scene in adobe flash cs6 actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, adobe, scene

I'm trying to make a loop animation scene where its like an eye opening and closing. I have one black rectangle that goes down and meets with another black rectangle going up to create the blink effect. Then in the middle I have a button that the viewer can click to go to the next scene. The problem is that before and after the button is pressed both scenes play simultaneously. How can I play the first loop scene and then stop it to play the next scene when a user presses that button? Thanks.

Comment: if you have a web server, put on there and send a link, or use skydrive, or dropbox, or rapidshare and any file sharing service.

Comment: I'm just not sure what you mean by "play simultaneously",  if you referring to using the Scene features of the flash timeline, I don't know how they would play at the same time.  Unless you mean they loop indefinately, in which case a simple **stop();** command at the end of each timeline would suffice

Comment: ok here is my dropbox link let me know if it works. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy1dlash9ckqao8/Untitled-1.fla

Comment: works, but I don't have CS6 so I can't open it - I should have anticipated that from the title of your question.

Comment: its ok, I will try to add the stop(); in my code and see if it works, thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried the code and it seems to work. I click on the button and the scene is changed with no loop. But before I press the button it plays both scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your respective scenes to stop. Otherwise flash player will just move on to the next scene automatically after the last frame of the previous scene (and loop back to the first scene after the last frame of the final scene).

In flash, open your first scene and open the timeline view. scroll to the very end of your timeline, add a new layer, on the very last frame of your timeline on your new layer, create a keyframe (F6 on windows). With that new keyframe selected, open the code editor (F9 on windows) and put in the command `stop();`  OR if you want the current scene to keep looping (without moving on the next scene) put in the command `gotoAndPlay(1);`

If you want your other scene to stop as well at the end, repeat the above steps on it's timeline.

Comment: well the thing is that I want scene 1 to keep looping until the user presses the button for scene 2.

Comment: then instead of stop(); , use **gotoAndPlay(1);**